# Openmdao 1.7.3 error with unicode variables in python2

Tags: openmdao

In the file openmdao/core/problem.py on lines such as 1619 and 1638, it checks if a variable is a string by using:

```
isinstance(inp, str)
```

however, this will return false if inp is unicode in python2, and eventually cause the program to raise an exception.  In python2, the correct syntax is:

```
isinstance(inp, basestring)
```

I understand that basestring is not available in python 3, but there are several ways to write python 2/3 compatible code.  Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

feel free to submit a pull request, but please add a test that checks the new functionality